# Should a sequence of entire functions that converges on the disk to an entire function converge on the whole plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, holomorphic-functions

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of entire functions and let $f$ be an entire function such that, for every compact subset $K$ of the unit disk, it holds that: 
$$\|f_n-f\|_{L^\infty(K)}\rightarrow0, n\rightarrow\infty.$$
Is it true that if $H$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ then
$$\|f_n-f\|_{L^\infty(H)}\rightarrow0, n\rightarrow\infty?$$
My guess is that the answer is no, and probably the counterexample is obvious, but I'm having hard time finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(z)=(\frac z 2)^{n}$ is a counter-example. Here $f=0$ and you don't have convegrence when $H=\{3\}$.

Comment: Why did you divide by $2$?

Comment: Silly of me! I was thinking of convergence on the closed disk